# PHP crashing on occasion - APC error?

Tags: php

Any thoughts on this?  We've had this happen twice recently.  Basically, every page throws a fatal error, fixed by an apache restart.  Here's what's in the log, repeated over and over.

[Tue Apr 13 15:18:12 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.2] PHP Fatal error:  Internal Zend error - Missing class information for  in /www/sites/ep/vogoo/items.php on line 31
[Tue Apr 13 15:18:12 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.2] PHP Fatal error:  Internal Zend error - Missing class information for  in /www/sites/ep/vogoo/items.php on line 31
[Tue Apr 13 15:18:13 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.2] PHP Fatal error:  Internal Zend error - Missing class information for  in /www/sites/ep/vogoo/items.php on line 31

Looking around, this may be an issue with APC?
http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16120&edit=1
(We're running 3.0.19, which shows as latest stable on pecl.)

Thoughts?  I increased the amount of memory apc uses, but the problem just happened again.

Comment: Try to be more precise with your configuration (php, server, if you use a framework and so on...) It'll be more comfortable for the reader, and you might get better answer.

Comment: We're now running php 5.3.6 and apc 3.1.6.  No frameworks.  The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing APC's memory would not fix this. Did you try simply turning it off and checking if issue persist?

Comment: Did not try turning it off.  This error occurs infrequently and we cannot predictably reproduce. We "solved" it by checking the log every minute and clearing the apc cache if the error case is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty weird, but the error says that Zend encounter an error... So I think your Zend engine is messed up. Maybe some component conflict that stop crash apache.

From the link you posted, it seem that the error appear with include_once/require_once function try remove the _once. That might do the trick.

Hope this will help.